# Why Orion-ld after 0.8.0 is not supporting the formation of service/subservice in quantumleap logs?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, cratedb

Any version of orion-ld after 0.8.0 is not supporting the formation of service/subservice in quantumleap logs, **thereby no table-schema formed with "mt" prefix in crate-db**. But tables are formed with "et" prefix followed by entity type containing quantumleap persisted data.

Below is my example quantumleap subscription

```
{
  "description": "Notify me of animal locations",
  "type": "Subscription",
  "entities": [{"type": "Device"}],
  "watchedAttributes": ["location", "status", "heartRate"],
  "notification": {
    "attributes": ["location", "status", "heartRate"],
    "format": "normalized",
    "endpoint": {
      "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
      "accept": "application/json",
    }
  },
   "throttling": 10,
   "@context": "http://context:3000/data-models/ngsi-context.jsonld"
}
```

How to solve this problem?
I am following this tutorial [text](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Time-Series-Data/tree/NGSI-LD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in QuantumLeap. Orion-LD (NGSI-LD) is a strange beast in that it is a fork of Orion classic (NGSI-v2) and I guess that for notifications, it was still forwarding the `fiware-service` and `fiware-service-path` Headers by default until 0.8.0

According to the 1.7.1 ETSI spec, *5.2.15 Endpoint* includes an array called **receiverInfo** which can be used to send arbitrary headers - if you set this to include a `fiware-service` key-value pair, then QuantumLeap will create an mt element for the tenant.

QuantumLeap *should* be reading `NGSILD-Tenant` as an alias of `fiware-service`

Something like this:

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
-H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
--data-raw '{
  "description": "Notify me using the openiot fiware-service",
  "type": "Subscription",
  "entities": [{"type": "FillingLevelSensor"}],
  "watchedAttributes": ["filling"],
  "notification": {
    "attributes": ["filling", "location"],
    "format": "normalized",
    "endpoint": {
      "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "receiverInfo": [
        {
          "key": "fiware-service",
          "value": "openiot"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
   "@context": "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld"
}'
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Now it works as it supposed to be.